# How to import PyCharm settings?

Tags: pycharm, settings, jetbrains-ide

On my old machine I exported the settings of PyCharm to the settings.zip file.
unpacked the zip file, checked it in to a repo, and now I want to import the settings by creating a zip file again (`zip -r settings.zip settings`) and importing it like the original zip file and it doesn't work.

When I try to import the settings.zip I get:

```
The file ~/devenvconfig/pycharm/settings.zip contains no settings to import.
Please make sure you have generated the file using 'File|Export Settings' feature.
```

Any idea what's wrong here?

Comment: Just copy-paste files manually: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs

Comment: I wonder.. if the 'Import Settings' is just copying files over to the right directory, why wouldn't it just accept my files? Your comment does answer the questions in the title though.

Comment: It may be checking for some basic "integrity marker" that is missing. For example: 1) it expects `.jar` file; 2) I just exported my PhpStorm 2019.3 .. and I see zero-length file in archive with `IntelliJ IDEA Global Settings` name -- could easily be that marker.